# TLS header in content portion of HTTPS POST request hot handled well

Tags: tls, openssl, curl

We are trying to communicate from an embedded application to a device via HTTPS protocol. We are having difficulty doing so from the embedded application but can do so successfully from say Windows using Curl command. 
At the firmware level with the libraries we are using (libcurl, openssl) we are seeing an additional TLS header(line) prior to the content of the POST request (but after the HTTPS headers of the POST) whereas that header(line) is not there, when communicating to the device from Windows.

*Note* we are getting past the TLS handshake sucessfully in both scenarios.

The additional line is the …. 17 03 03 00 4d line displayed in the capture 
 for the HttpsClient below. The first capture shows communication between Windows Curl and the device. The second capture shows communication between embedded application and the device.
Locations like https://www.httpbin.org/post have no trouble handling this extra TLS header line as we are able to communicate to that url from the embedded application successfully.

On the embedded application the libraries versions are: Libcurl: 7.41.0 (February 25 2015 release) 
Openssl: openSSL 1.0.2h

We have not been informed what versions of libraries are being run on the device.

Has anyone dealt with this before or have any ideas on how to get around this?

Here are the captures ...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There  is no such thing as a "TLS header line". "17 03 03" in your output just means the beginning of a new TLS frame with application data (type 23, i.e. 0x17, followed by TLS protocol where 0x0303 means TLS 1.2).

The output you show instead means that one client is sending the POST header and body within a single TLS frame while the other client is sending the POST header in one frame and the POST body in a second frame. This is probably caused by the first client using a single SSL_write which includes header and body while the seconds client uses a SSL_write for the header and another for the body. This is both a perfectly valid behavior and you could even split the payload into even more TLS frames. This also means that the server probably needs to do multiple reads to get the full HTTP message (header and body).

If the server has problems with this then the server is broken. Such brokenness is often caused by he server authors trying to write their own HTTP stack by just looking at a few HTTP messages, instead of using an established stack or properly reading the standard. The standard clearly says where a HTTP message starts and where it ends. And since HTTP is set on top of a streaming protocol it might be possible that multiple reads are needed to get the full HTTP message.  This is probably the reason why it succeeds with some properly implement server but not with your broken server.

Comment: "_Such brokenness is often_" not even an HTTP thing. It's a TCP thing, caused by technically broken human description of TCP being repeated: TCP segmentation is quote often described as a variant of IP fragmentation, at the TCP level (or as AAL5...). Although the explanation will never explicitly say that TCP segment is the analog of IP fragment, that's so strongly implied that pretty everyone much gets that on first reading. And it's absolute pure BS. The very description of TCP as providing sending of messages bigger than MTU, reassembly, etc. is wrong. TCP provides octet stream, period.

Comment: The graphics used almost always use the same representation for TCP as for UDP, IP... this is bad bad bad. TCP implements a continuous stream of octets (for for each direction) and read(1) (if you are using the usual Unix API) can return any length of data smaller than what was sent, so there is no guaranteed relation between the number of calls to write(1) on one side and the number of returns from calls to read(1) on the other, unless you send exactly one octet each time.

Comment: HTTP/TCP and HTTP/TLS/TCP both exist and HTTP has the exact same operation in both cases. TLS does not just present a stream of octets to the application, but HTTP has no use of anything but a stream of octets. Any additional semantic provided by TLS cannot be used as HTTP is designed for TCP.

Comment: @curiousguy: While I agree that a wrong understanding of network protocols is a problem I don't think there is  any actual value added to this answer by your extensive (spanning multiple comments) rambling about a wrong understanding of TCP.

Comment: I don't think there is any actual value added to my alleged "rambling" by your short comment. ;)

Comment: Guys this issue has raised its head again. Looking at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/#streams_messages_and_frames there is a diagram that seems to be showing that for HTTP/1.1 the SDP headers and SDP data of a HTTP request are all in 1 frame. Then below that it shows that with HTTP 2.0 there are potentially separate frames for the headers  and data. So what I am asking is this ... if we are strictly following HTTP/1.1 as the captures above show, should the protocol be allowing for the multiple frames?

Comment: @C.Brady: I think you are misunderstanding things here. The link you show says nothing about frames in HTTP/1.1 but only talks about frames in HTTP/2. There is not even the concept of frames in HTTP/1.1 because it sits directly on the TCP stream (or TLS with HTTPS). But there is a concept of frames in HTTP/2 where these frames are a layer on top of TCP/TLS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think I used the wrong terminology in my comment. Thanks for the correction. I think the link was showing for HTTP/1.1 the SDP headers and data of a Post Request going out as one request, sent to the TCP layer. Whereas for HTTP/2 as you indicate the concept of frames could split up the one request into two frames. Hopefully I have now got the terminology correct.     But what I was asking is that "framing" feature seems to be a function of HTTP/2 and was asking whether it should be used in HTTPS when we send HTTP/1.1 in the captures above?

Comment: @Steffen UllrichHowever I just read at https://www.keycdn.com/blog/difference-between-http-and-https/  ... this statement ... "Because of browser support for HTTP/2, HTTPS is currently required to take advantage of it" ... which to me indicates that HTTPS is supposed to be using functionality in HTTP/2. Do you know this to be true?

Comment: @C.Brady: First I don't know what this SDP thing is you are referring to - I only know SDP as Session Description Protocol from SIP. Anyway, none of the images make any assumption how the data are handled at the TCP layer. And while the HTTP request is a structured message from the perspective of HTTP it is only some bytes from the perspective of TCP and can be arbitrarily split into packets because TCP is only a byte stream but not a message protocol. Similar HTTP/2 frames can be arbitrarily distributed over TCP packets.

Comment: @C.Brady: *"indicates that HTTPS is supposed to be using functionality in HTTP/2."* - please don't ask new questions in a comment. Anyway, HTTP/2 can be used on top of TCP or TLS same as HTTP/1.x, but browsers have implemented TLS  only.